# Image Source relative path from dynamic JS not loading correctly

Tags: javascript, html, image

I am trying to create image thumbnail inside my table row and hence created img element. However  , it gives the url of the image source with url encoding. for eg it appears as:

> file:///Users/codeFolder/images%E2%81%A9/square-small%E2%81%A9/00001.jpg

How do I make it show without any encodings and keeping the Javascript file simple?

```
var imgCell=tr.insertCell(0);

//append thumbnail image source
var img = document.createElement('img');

img.src = "images⁩/square-small⁩/"+ImageFileName+".jpg";

imgCell.appendChild(img);
```

Comment: I am looking for answer to a similar question, @admin, please help